# Duplicate boot params after grub2-mkconfig

Tags: fedora, boot, grub2, options

I removed the flags 'quiet' , 'splash' , and added others in the file /etc/default/grub, applied them: grub2-mkconfig -o . After a reboot, the kernel boot flags began to double. **With each 'grub2-mkconfig -o ' command and reload the number of options increases.** An entry 'unknown parameters' appeared in the log. OS - Fedora 38. Screenshot of the log in the link below.

/etc/default/grub

> GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
> GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
> GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
> GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
> GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rhgb tsc=unstable & trace_clock=local"
> GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
> GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=true
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="rhgb splash initcall_blacklist=amd_pstate_init amd_pstate.enable=0 tsc=unstable & trace_clock=local"

---

`cat /proc/cmdline`

```
BOOT_IMAGE=(hd0,gpt2)/vmlinuz-6.3.12-200.fc38.x86_64 root=UUID=eba5bfa3-0cef-458d-ad0c-b629bfd7538e ro rootflags=subvol=root rhgb tsc=unstable options root=UUID=eba5bfa3-0cef-458d-ad0c-b629bfd7538e ro rootflags=subvol=root rhgb tsc=unstable options root=UUID=eba5bfa3-0cef-458d-ad0c-b629bfd7538e ro rootflags=subvol=root rhgb rd.plymouth=0 plymouth.enable=0 tsc=unstable options root=UUID=eba5bfa3-0cef-458d-ad0c-b629bfd7538e ro rootflags=subvol=root rhgb rd.plymouth=0 tsc=unstable options root=UUID=eba5bfa3-0cef-458d-ad0c-b629bfd7538e ro rootflags=subvol=root rhgb tsc=unstable options root=UUID=eba5bfa3-0cef-458d-ad0c-b629bfd7538e ro rootflags=subvol=root rhgb quiet trace_clock=local trace_clock=local trace_clock=local trace_clock=local trace_clock=local rhgb splash initcall_blacklist=amd_pstate_init amd_pstate.enable=0 tsc=unstable options root=UUID=eba5bfa3-0cef-458d-ad0c-b629bfd7538e ro rootflags=subvol=root rhgb tsc=unstable options root=UUID=eba5bfa3-0cef-458d-ad0c-b629bfd7538e ro rootflags=subvol=root rhgb rd.plymouth=0 plymouth.enable=0 tsc=unstable options root=UUID=eba5bfa3-0cef-458d-ad0c-b629bfd7538e ro rootflags=subvol=root rhgb rd.plymouth=0 tsc=unstable options root=UUID=eba5bfa3-0cef-458d-ad0c-b629bfd7538e ro rootflags=subvol=root rhgb tsc=unstable options root=UUID=eba5bfa3-0cef-458d-ad0c-b629bfd7538e ro rootflags=subvol=root rhgb quiet trace_clock=local trace_clock=local trace_clock=local trace_clock=local trace_clock=local
```

Output of the kernel boot log:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-eohEvSaf6_6f5s0-qd39J2tvaXhcysv/view?usp=sharing

**How can i fix this?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Solved after kernel update to 6.4.4 version! Boot settings are configured correctly. There are no duplicates.